# Matrix-shaped list

Tags: r, list, matrix, data-structures

Occasionally, I've written buggy R code that produced an object that `print`ed like a matrix, but where the elements were vectors. It might look something like this:

```
        [,1]           [,2]           [,3]
[1,]    character,2    character,2    character,2
[2,]    character,2    character,2    character,2
[3,]    character,2    character,2    character,2
```

I've never *intended* to create one before, but now I'm working on a project where this data structure could be useful.

What is it? How do I make one? What are its properties? For iterating over rows and columns, how does its efficiency compare to a nested list, an array, or a list of matrices?

Comment: It's a matrix of lists.  To make one, you can do `matrix(list(c("a", "b")))` for example

Comment: @RichardScriven so it's just a list with a `.Dim` attribute? That's my impression based on `dput(matrix(list(c("a", "b"))))`. This is really cool and I wonder why nobody does it. At any rate you should post that as an answer.

Comment: It's actually a matrix of objects, which as you say is just a list with a dimension attribute.  You can put anything you want in it, including functions.  It works basically like a list, except that you can access it with 2-dimensional indices.

Comment: You can also access items in a non-dimensioned lists with 2 or greater length vectors.

Comment: @BondedDust I know about that, but this isn't a nested list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making one is fairly trivial:

```
mtx <- matrix( list(letters[1:2]), 4,4)
mtx
#----------
     [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]       
[1,] Character,2 Character,2 Character,2 Character,2
[2,] Character,2 Character,2 Character,2 Character,2
[3,] Character,2 Character,2 Character,2 Character,2
[4,] Character,2 Character,2 Character,2 Character,2
```

The attribute (and the function that retrieves it) is named "dim". I would not expect it to be very much different in terms of access efficiency. Matrices in R are really just folded vectors.