# Forcing function in ODE

Tags: r, differential-equations

I have a system of Ordinary Differential equation which contains a forcing function R_0. The forcing function has a formula to be calculated at each time step. I tried to use `approxfunc()` in R, but when I print R_0_matrix I got (?) on the R_0 column at each time point and I got this error message when I run R_0_value

```
 Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I don't know where is my mistake in the code,any help will be appreciated

Here is a part of my code:

```
# define model paramters
parameters <- c(N = 3.2*10^6,L =1000/15,dimm = 1/1.07, d_in = 75/365, d_treat0 = 2/52, p1 = 0.87, p2 = 0.08, k = 0.082, eta0 = 0.05, R_m =1.23,amp = 0.67,phi = 3/12)

# R_0 Forcing Function
t <- seq(0, 100, by = 0.1)
R_0 <-function(t,paramters){
    with(as.list(parameters),{
    R_0=R_m*amp*cos(2*pi*(t-phi))+R_m
    return(R_0)
    })
}

R_0_matrix <-cbind(t,R_0)
R_0_value<- approxfun(x=R_0_matrix[,1], y= R_0_matrix[,2], method="linear", rule=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

`R_0` is a function. So `cbind(t, R_0)` is probably not what you intended, since it tries to create a matrix where one column is numeric and the other is a function. See what happens, for example, if you type this into the console: `cbind(1:10, function(x) {x})`. Probably you meant to do this:

```
R_0_t = R_0(t, parameters)

R_0_matrix <- cbind(t, R_0_t)
R_0_value <- approxfun(x=R_0_matrix[,1], y= R_0_matrix[,2], method="linear", rule=2)
```

Naming the function `R_0` and then also calling the calculated object within the function environment `R_0` may have caused some confusion. Even though the function creates an object called `R_0` *inside the function environment*, the object `R_0` that exists in the global environment is the function itself. To avoid confusion it's better to use different names for the function and any objects created inside the function environment.

Furthermore, the function does not return an object called `R_0` to the global environment. It just returns the vector of numbers that result from evaluating the function `R_0`. The name of this returned vector in the global environment is whatever you assign when you call the function (`R_0_t` in the code sample above).

And just to check the approximation function:

```
plot(t[1:30], R_0_t[1:30], type="l", lwd=2)
lines(t[1:30], R_0_value(t[1:30]), col="red", lwd=6, lty=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Why in the world doesn't `cbind(1:10, function(x) {x})` throw an error?

Comment: I agree. Seems like it ought to.

Comment: Ah I see, it's one of those [matrix-shaped lists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29130910/2954547). The function is coerced to a list and recycled, then it's printed as `?` to confuse you. Could be an interesting feature in some kind of simulation, where you generate a function at every point along a grid. Then again, you could always just write _one_ function and pass the grid coordinates as arguments...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, its benefit me a lot. But I still has the problem that the value of R_0_t = to ?